# C++ Как правильно преобразовать значение из файла в int

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Приложение должно считывать из файла(.ini) значения width и height. При создании окна использовать эти параметры. Но, при запуске, открывается input.c и указывает на строку:

```
 if ( integer64 )
      *(__int64 UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned __int64)num64;
 else
 if (longone)
=====>*(long UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned long)number;<=====     
 else
      *(short UNALIGNED *)pointer = (unsigned short)number;
```

Как я понимаю, полученное значение(8 байт), превышает допустимый(4 байта).
Есть две структуры:

```
struct ConfigStruct
{
  int iSW, iSH;
}ini;

struct ConfigResult
{
  int cSW, cSH;
}res;
```

В ConfigStruct, записываются полученные из файла значения. В ConfigResult, я хотел записать преобразованные в int значения.

Эта функция считывает с файла необходимые значения:

```
int ConfigRW::ReadConfig(char* filename)
{
ifstream fcf;

string line;
fcf.open(filename,ios::in);

while (!fcf.eof())
{
    getline(fcf,line);

    if(line.find("iScreenWidth = ")!=line.npos)
    {
        sscanf_s(line.c_str(),"iScreenWidth = %d",&ini.iSW);
        //Нужно преобразовать значение в int
        res.cSW = ini.iSW;
    }
    if(line.find("iScreenHeight = ")!=line.npos)
    {
        sscanf_s(line.c_str(),"iScreenHeight = %d",&ini.iSH);
        //Нужно преобразовать значение в int
        res.cSH = ini.iSH;
    }
    }
    fcf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

В WinMain, присвоить значения из структуры ConfigResult, к переменным: ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight.

```
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevious, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Config->ReadConfig("../Test/Settings.ini");
    int ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight;

    ScreenWidth = Config->res.cSW;
    ScreenHeight = Config->res.cSH;
    //ScreenWidth = 1280;
    //ScreenHeight = 720;

    Prog->WinClass(hInstance);
    Prog->WinCreate(hInstance,"Test Application",ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
    Prog->WinLoop(msg);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно преобразовать значения?

Comment: GetPrivateProfileString() + atoi() попробуйте...

Comment: У вас, похоже, проблема с преображованием типов. Скажите, как объявлены `pointer`, `num64` и `number`?